# Continuity of a two variable function at$(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have to prove or disprove the continuity of the function at $(0,0)$ which is given by:

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}\frac{\sin^{-1}(x+2y)}{ \tan^{-1}(2x+4y)}&\text{ if } 
 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\  \frac 12 &\text{ if } (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}.$$

I consider $x+2y=t$ where $t$ approaches to $0$. This reduces the two variable function to that of a single variable in $t$. The resulting function is:

$g(t)= \frac{\sin^{-1}(t)}{\tan^{-1}(2t)}$ for non-zero $t$ and $\frac12$ for $t=0$.

This function is continuous at $t=0$. Does it imply the continuity of the original two-variable function at$(0,0)$. What are the other ways of checking continuity at the said point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the answer is yes. The continuity of $g$ ensures the continuity of $f$. Basically, we are considering the functions $h(x,y)=x + 2y$ and $g(t) = \frac{\sin^{-1}(t)}{\tan^{-1}(2t)}$ and just saying that
$f = g \circ h$. The results on  limits and continuity of composed functions guarantee your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your way is fine, since we have that by $t=x+2y \to 0$

$$\frac{\sin^{-1}(t)}{\tan^{-1}(2t)}=\frac12\frac{\sin^{-1}(t)}{t}\frac{2t}{\tan^{-1}(2t)} \to \frac12$$

we can conclude that the give function is continuous at $(0,0)$.